# What is being said during the Siege on Home?

Tags: final-fantasy

In *Final Fantasy X*, during the siege on Home by the Guado you can hear something being said over the speaker system in Al Bhed.

It sounds like 2 words with the very end sounding like a "あ (a)" sound (though it could sounds like か (ka) or ま (ma)). At first I thought it might be "Red Alert" but "Red Alert" translates to

> nat ymand
>   Pronounced: "nah-te aemahn-de"

Source: [Al Bhed Translator](http://stefangagne.com/albhed.html)

I'm looking for a creditable source which translates what's being said since no subtitles are ever shown.

Comment: Final Fantasy X is a game, isn't it?

Comment: @Alchemist yes however anime themed games and to that extension JRPGs are on topic here so long as the question isn't about game mechanics and given that the answer to this doesn't at all help with gameplay but gives me a bit more understanding of the Al Bhed I figured it would still be on topic here

Comment: i see. So all square enix games qualify for this, right?

Comment: @Alchemist I'm not sure about all (like Tomb Raider, Hitman and Deus Ex) but I think at the least Final Fantasy and Dragon Quest. might just check with the Meta on Dragon Quest but it's art style is very similar to that of Dragon Ball Z so I think it qualifies

Comment: Yeah and Kingdom Hearts too. That's definitely the anime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's *probably* "Ajanouha ihtan!", which means "Everyone under!"**

There's [a forum thread on GameFAQs about this particular question](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/60747335).

Post #8 by erict1628,

> It's "Ajanouha ihtan!", which means "Everyone under!" in Al Bhed.
>
> Cid is telling everyone to get to the Airship because he's going to level Home.

but Post #10 by Fallacia (an Al Bhed expert),

> This is actually one bit of Al Bhed I've never been able to fully get. I've never fully agreed with the "everyone under" interpretation. That may have been what was in the script, but the VA's pronunciation changes it a little bit. There's no pronunciation at all of the "uha" for "one" at the end of everyone. Instead, what he's saying is actually much closer to "ajano ihtan," with the spacing making it sound like "Ajanoiht-an." It tripped me up for a long time, because I had thought that he was saying something that sounded more like, "anmanoehk," "ammanoehk," "or amanoeh," all of which are nonsense when translated. With those, you get erlering, ellerying, and eleryin.
>
> I'm willing to believe that it was supposed to have been "everyone under," but instead it comes out as "Every Under" thanks to poor pronunciation of a language that none of the voice actors were actually supposed to have known. The same thing happens when people try to speak other languages for which they haven't developed an ear or just aren't native speakers. Even if the pronunciation isn't entirely too bad, it could still be completely unintelligible to a native speaker thanks to intonation, pausing between syllables, manufactured sounds, muted sounds, and a general sense that the person themselves hasn't created an association for the words they're saying, almost as if they are reading instead of speaking.

---

There's [a same question posted on Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1484822974), with the answer,

> 「ヒアシリハンヘモ！」と繰り返し言ってるやつのことかな？（聞き取りにくいですが。）
>   ヒアシリハンヘモはアルベド語で、「地下に避難せよ」という意味です。
>
> 《補足より》
>   「ヒアっ（ｼﾘ）ハンっ（ﾍﾓ）」みたいに喋ってるんだと。アルティマニア情報だった気が。あとＦＦの用語辞典Wikiの、アルベドホームの欄に載ってました。
>
> Is it the guy who was repeating "Hiasiri hanhemo!" (it's difficult to be heard though)?
>   In Al Bhed, "Hiasiri hanhemo" means "Evacuate to the basement".
>
> (Addendum)
>   It's spoken like "Hia(siri) han(hemo)".
>   I think Ultimania (guidebook) has this info. Also it's mentioned on [Al Bhed Home's page on Japanese FF Wiki](http://ffdic.wikiwiki.jp/?%C3%CF%CC%BE%A1%A6%C3%CF%B7%C1%2F%A1%DA%A5%A2%A5%EB%A5%D9%A5%C9%A4%CE%A5%DB%A1%BC%A5%E0%A1%DB).